# how to show same drop down list in every sheet of an excel work book

Tags: excel

I want to know any formula that show a same drop down list on every sheet of excel work book that can be control from any sheet. actually i have place a if formula in some cells but the condition cell placed on top cell through a drop down list. All sheets data is based on that condition. my problem is that if some one want to see its desire data from my list he has to come on sheet 1. I want to show that drop down list on every sheet so one can control it from any sheet and get it desired information.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to data validation, then put your item list in a separate tab and in data validation select "list" where you point to the range of items previously defined.

Comment: Thanks Robert, Drop down list through data validation has placed on sheet 1, but i want to show and control this same dropdown list on every sheet (e.g. sheet 2, sheet 3 etc). BR

Comment: Once you have your list of items in a separate sheet (preferably a named range, which you can then select in the data validation with the F3 key), you just copy the data validation input cell to all other sheets. I feel that I am missing something because this is too obvious, so tell me in more detail what you want.